# PhpStorm Import data from CSV file to MySQL, Cyrillic problem

Tags: php, mysql, csv, encoding, phpstorm

I have problem with encoding while trying to import data from CSV file to MySQL database in PhpStorm. The CSV file contains Cyrillic symbols. I've read some articles, tried many things, but none of them worked for me.

In my.ini file I changed:

`collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci` to `collation_server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and
`character_set_server=utf8` to `character_set_server=utf8mb4`

but the result was still the same.

That's my CSV file:

```
NAME_1,NAME_2,NAME_3
Vladimir,Ivanov,Kaziyski
ИВАН,ПЕТРОВ,ГЕОРГИЕВ
John,Lee,Smith
ПЕТЪР,ЙОРДАНОВ,ПЕТРОВ
```

In PhpStorm I click right-button on the database which I will import data and then I click:

[image]

then I chose the CSV file

[image]

and in the Data Preview section everything looks normal, encoding is set to UTF-8

[image]

and after that I get this error

[image]

Here is the log:

```
2:1: Data truncation: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x98\xD0\x92\xD0\x90...' for column `current_db`.`csv_data`.`NAME_1` at row 2
3:1: Data truncation: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x98\xD0\x92\xD0\x90...' for column `current_db`.`csv_data`.`NAME_1` at row 1
4:1: Data truncation: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x98\xD0\x92\xD0\x90...' for column `current_db`.`csv_data`.`NAME_1` at row 2
5:1: Data truncation: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x9F\xD0\x95\xD0\xA2...' for column `current_db`.`csv_data`.`NAME_1` at row 1
```

I've searched this error and tried almost all solutions, but nothing worked. The problem for sure is Cyrillic. Does anyone with PhpStorm had the same issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

utf8 vs utf8mb4 does not matter for Cyrillic, only for Emoji and Chinese.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  I suspect you did not change the `CHARACTER SET` for the column(s) that will receive the Cyrillic characters.

Comment: create table csv_data ( NAME_1 TEXT null, NAME_2 TEXT null, NAME_3 TEXT null)

Comment: @yoff - No, please run the command `SHOW CREATE TABLE csv_data` and provide the output.

Comment: Thank you! The schema's charset was set to latin1. I went in phpmyadmin and changed the Collation to utf8_unicode_ci!